# getting no such method error in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi

I am getting the following error as shown below

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/util/Region;)I
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createMergeRegion(JRXlsExporter.java:440)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.initCreateCell(JRXlsExporter.java:419)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createTextCell(JRXlsExporter.java:381)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.exportText(JRXlsExporter.java:314)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:381)
```

i am using the below poi jars as shown in the class path and also jasperreports 1.2.5 jar please advise i have upgraded poi jars from 2.5 to 3 so please advise do i need to upgrade jasperreports-1.2.5.jar also to be in synch with the latest poi jars

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-3.5-FINAL.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-contrib-3.5-final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-scratchpad-3.5-FINAL.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>  
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar"/>

    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="thirdparty/POI-3.5/jsr173_1.0_api.jar"/>
```

although i have done some analysis and found this url  `http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531433/save-excel-jasperviewer`
which suggest with poi up gradation i should upgrade my jasper jars also

for jasper reports i have not upgraded i am using jasper reports 1.2.5 jar should i upgrade that also , folks please advise

Comment: Apache POI 3.5 is rather old, I'd suggest you upgrade that, and also your Jasper if that isn't the most recent too

Comment: Well I use mostly final one jars for example in case of poi I use poi 3.5 final jars so shall I go for poi 3.10 final jar please advise and let's say should I keep other dependent jars like ooxml and ooxml schemas to also 3.10 versions please advise

Comment: The most recent final release is 3.13. You should find out what the most recent Jasper release is, upgrade to that, and the POI jars it depends on. See the [Apache POI changes list](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) for the fixes you'll get by upgrading!

Comment: The most recent Jasper Reports is [6.2 which depends on Apache POI 3.10.1 final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.2.0). I can't see anything newer on the Jasper side using POI 3.13, so that may be the best you can manage

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is typical error when not using correct version of libraries.

Jasper report uses **multiple** libraries which can be found in its distribution (in folder `lib`), they should all be included in `classpath`

[Jasper report releases](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases)

If you are using Jasper reports 1.2.5 this is its release [Jasper report v 1.2.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/archive/jasperreports/JasperReports%201.2.5/). You will find correct libraries to include in your `classpath` in folder `lib`.

However there is no doubt that is better to upgrade to latest version (when posted this answer 6.2.0), specially if you need to export to `xlxs`, `ooxml`, `XSSF`, this it **not supported** in 1.2.5.

**Note**: jasper report has change is file format definition from `DTD` to `XSD` schema in newer version so you may need to change your headers in .jrxml (or use old .jrxml compiler)